# Cache-control in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to optimize page serving time on Google app engine, but I'm struggling at getting the effect I want.

in my app.yaml, I used the following directive:

```
handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets
  expiration: 7d
```

under the asset folder, I have all my images, css and js. By using the 7d expiration, I would have expected the browser to use the local cached files and not come to my app for 7 days.

Although, in the response headers for my assets I get the following:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=604800
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
```

I understand that with these headers, the browser will check on my app if the file as changed before releasing the cached version. (I can effectively see a bunch of 304 corresponding to my files under the asset folder, for both refresh and simple page load).

Is there a way in Google app engine to configure the cache behavior so the browser will not comeback for those files for 7d (on a simple page load), as specified in the expiration? (i.e. removing the "no-cache" from cache-control header)

P.S. I dont want to enable PageSpeed on my app. I want full control on the html served.

Comment: I'm finding PageSpeed caches private information from ajax requests! I'm trying to set cache control: No-store but I still get cache control: private

Answer (score 6):

Are you logged on with an Admin-account by any chance? AppEngine adds some [private headers about the costs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/reference/request-response-headers#headers_added_or_replaced) for Admins and disables caching because that data is private. Logging out solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the expiration directive and GAE sends the following as the default cache setting:

Cache-Control:public, max-age=600

Can you try removing expiration: 7d and see if GAE only sends 1 Cache-Control header?

Answer (score 0):

How you load your page in the browser might be relevant here:

- If you press Ctrl and reload the page using the refresh button, that will cause an unconditional reload of your resources with 200s returned.
- If you just reload using the refresh button (or equivalent key like F5), conditional requests will be sent and 304s will be returned for static resources.
- If you press enter in the address box, add the page to your bookmarks and load from there, or visit the page from a hyperlink, the cache max-age should work as expected.

Comment: Those aren't likely to cause the server to send `no-cache, must-revalidate`.